# Number pattern in python using the given code snippet

Tags: python

Well the question might seem to be very easy i.e. to print a star pattern like

```
1
22
333
4444
```

For an input of 5

But the trick is that we have to make this pattern only by completing the following lines of code:

```
for i in range (1,input()):
    print {Here goes the code}
```

Code can not extend more than 2 lines

[Link to the question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-quest-1)

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers of the form `x` repeated `y` times are called [repdigits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit). You can produce such a number simply by calculation. The challenge simplified this by asking you to produce repdigits where `x == y`; `y` repeats of the digit `y`.

You can produce a repeated `1`, `y` times with the formula `(10 ** y - 1) / 9`; ten to the power `y` produces a `1` with `y` zeros. Subtract 1 and you have `y` nines. Divide that by `9` to get `y` ones:

```
>>> y = 7
>>> 10 ** y
10000000
>>> 10 ** y - 1
9999999
>>> (10 ** y - 1) // 9
1111111
```

Now all you have to do is multiply this by `y` to get `y` repeated `y` digits:

```
>>> y * (10 ** y - 1) // 9
7777777
```

Now you have a formula for producing a repdigit for any given `y`:

```
for y in range(1, input()):
    print(y * (10 ** y - 1) // 9)
```

No string operations needed; all that is needed is arithmetic operators.

Demo:

```
>>> sample = 5
>>> for y in range(1, 5):
...     print(y * (10 ** y - 1) // 9)
... 
1
22
333
4444
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `*` for string repetition:

```
for i in range (1,input()):               # Use int(input()) in 3.x
    print(str(i) * i)
```

Comment: anything related to strings is not to be used